# Ported carboy vs. siphoning?

Tags: carboy, siphon, better-bottle

I'm considering purchasing a couple of [these plastic ported carboys](http://www.austinhomebrew.com/product_info.php?products_id=10775). From reading the description, it seems that I'd be able to rack directly into secondary and/or bottles without the need for siphoning.

Does anyone use these and can anyone recommend for/against the use of ported carboys as opposed to siphoning?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use them, so I can't help out too much. But, check out some of the answers here for some insight: http://brewadvice.com/questions/tagged/better-bottle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using them a year ago. I think they are *fantastic*! I love being able to to simply open the port and transfer my liquids around.

I haven't had any troubles with leaking or breaking. The parts seem solid enough. I highly recommend the Better Bottles with Ports.

Comment: Seems like they'd be slightly harder to clean, no?  That was always my concern with the ported bottle.  Racking canes and tubing is cheap and I replace it every 6 months or so.  Can the port be removed and thoroughly cleaned?

Comment: The spigot for the port is very easy to remove. I remove it after every batch, clean it, and allow all parts to dry. I'll sanitize and reassemble just before adding the next batch of wort.

Answer (score 2):

I just started using ported Better Bottles myself, and have been really pleased with the results.

I did have a problem at first with getting the tubing to fit tight enough in the valve to siphon off the beer, but the Better Bottle web site has very clear instructions on the correct tube sizes to use, and that fixed my problem.